# Python 2.7 IndexError: list index out of range, converting file

Tags: python, performance, csv, jmeter

I have a code for convert Jmeter JTL FILE TO CSV, but when I run the code, I have the following error: IndexError: list index out of range in line 32

This is the code

```
import sys
import re
import datetime
import time

startTime = time.time()
cnt = 0
cnt2 = 0
failCnt = 0
reCompile = re.compile("\s([^\s]*?)=\"(.*?)\"")
delimiterCharacterOut = ","

def writeCSVLine(line):

      x = reCompile.findall(line)
      a = dict((row[0], row[1]) for row in x)

      try:
          a['ts1'] = str(int(int(a['ts'])/1000))
          x = str(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(a['ts1'])))[0:19]
          b = a['ts'] + ",\"" + x + "\"," + a['t'] + "," + a['lt'] + ",\"" + a['s'] + "\",\"" + a['lb'] + "\"," + a['rc'] + ",\"" + a['rm'] + "\",\"" + a['tn'] + "\",\"" + a['dt'] + "\"," + a['by'] + ",\"" + a['sc'] + "\"," + a['ec'] + ",\"" + a['ng'] + "\"," + a['na'] + ",\"" + a['hn'] + "\"," + a['in'] + "\n" 
      except:
         return -1 
      o.write(b)
      return 1 

print "Splitting JTL file"

try:

     runArgv = sys.argv            #Save the command line
     jtlInfile = str(sys.argv[1])  #Name of JTL input file
     cvsOutfile = str(sys.argv[2]) # Name of CVS output file
     reFilter = str(sys.argv[3])   # Filter the labels (lb) for the filter 

except:
      print "Error: Input format: <input file> <output file> <Filter by regular expression>"
      raise 

try:

     f = open(jtlInfile, "r")
     o = open(cvsOutfile, "w") 

except:

     raise 

print "Filtering on regular expression : " + reFilter
cmpFilter = re.compile(reFilter)
# o.write("timestamp" + ",\""+ "datetime" + "\n")
o.write("timeStamp" + ",\"" + "datetime" + "\"," + "elapsed" + "," + "Latency" + ",\"" + "success" + "\",\"" + "label" + "\"," + "responseCode" + ",\"" + "responseMessage" + "\",\"" + "threadName"+ "\",\"" + "dataType" + "\"," + "bytes" + ",\"" + "SampleCount" + "\"," + "ErrorCount" + ",\"" + "grpThreads" + "\"," + "allThreads" + ",\"" + "Hostname" + "\"," + "IdleTime" + "\n")

for line in f:

     try:
           if cmpFilter.search(line):
                 returnVal = writeCSVLine(line)
                 if returnVal<0:
                      failCnt += 1 
                 else:
                     cnt2 += 1 
     except:
           print 'Error in line : ', cnt, line
           raise 
     cnt += 1 

endTime = time.time()
print "Time taken : ", str(endTime-startTime)
print "Lines processed : ", cnt
print "Lines that passed the filter : ", cnt2
print "Lines skipped (error?) : ", failCnt
f.close()
o.close()
```

[Log de CMD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8S2xM.png)

The base tutorial is in : http://balasoftwaretesting.blogspot.com/2012/03/converting-jmeter-jtl-file-to-csv-file.html?spref=bl

Comment: Please let us know where the error is. Is there a simpler example that shows the error?

Comment: Oh wait... is was in that jpeg. Putting the error in the question can help. Your problem is with `jtlInfile = str(sys.argv[1])`. It means that you didn't call the program with the expected parameters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking into the script, you need to pass 3 command line arguments:

1. Source JTL file
2. Target CSV file
3. Regular expression filter

So you need to execute the script like:

```
JtltoCsv_Jmeter.py example.jtl example.csv "(.*)"
```

Also there is an option to switch JMeter's results output format to CSV, in order to do so use one of the following steps:

1. Add `jmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv` line to *user.properties* file (lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)
2. Pass the property value via -J command line argument as:

   ```
   jmeter -Jjmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv
   ```

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of passing, setting and overriding them.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`sys.argv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv) docs, `sys.argv` is the list of command line arguments passed to a Python script.

Your command line log shows that you ran `python JtltoCsv_Jmeter.py`, which would result in an empty list for `sys.argv`. The tutorial provides a jtl file as an argument to `JtltoCsv_Jmeter.py`:

```
JtltoCsv_Jmeter.py C:\JtlToCsvConverter\input\sample.jtl
```

So it looks like maybe an error in copy/paste :)

Comment: Good answer except `argv` won't be empty... `argv[0]` will have the script name, and OP needs 3 paramters.

Comment: But I use, the Runme.bat